# In Django, how do you update all the values at once in a form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I new to Django and trying to use it to create something.  I am stuck on getting it to update the row I want.  I don't want to add a row.  I believe that in order to do this I have to set the values individually by some sort of loop.  Is that correct?  How would I create a loop so it can assigned the values without knowing the names of the columns?

```
if request.POST:
        form = GeneralConfigurationUpdateForm(instance=instance, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            #
            # HERE I NEED TO SET ALL THE VALUES for the row in GeneralConfiguration models
            #
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "You update was successfull")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('generalconfig/update/')
```

Answer (score 0):

To update something, here is the general flow:

1. Try to fetch the object from the primary key, which is normally passed in from the URL as a parameter called `pk`.
2. If this `pk` is not valid, display an error page.
3. Fetch the object with this `pk` and then initialize a `ModelForm`with it as the instance.
4. Validate this form with data from the request.
5. If this form is valid, execute form.save(), which will update the record.
6. Redirect the user to a thank you page (to prevent reloading of the page and doing multiple updates).

Here is some code that implements the above:

```
def update_something(request, pk=None):
   something = get_object_or_404(SomethingClass, pk=pk)
   form = SomethingForm(request.POST or None,
                        request.FILES or None, instance=something)
   if form.is_valid():
       form.save() # This does the magic of updating the record with
                   # the data from the form
       return redirect('/thanks')
   else:
       return render(request, 'update_form.html', {'form': form})
```